# Javascript functions' prototype is shared between objects??

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, prototype

All the resources I have found, it says that if we use Javascript prototype pattern, that functions' prototype is shared between all the objects for that particular type.
that means the following;

```
function TestObj(){
}

TestObj.prototype = {
    cVar: 15,
    increase: function(){
        this.cVar++;
    }
};

var a = new TestObj();
var b = new TestObj();
a.increase();
console.log(a.cVar); // 16
console.log(b.cVar); // 15 ??
```

Now my question is, shouldn't the b.cVar be 16? why is it 15 then? And if it is 15 that means the TestObj with protype is not shared between objects.

Do you know??

Comment: Your getting confused by the terminology, and `TestObject` `a` is the only `TestObject` that you call `increase()` on so it makes sense that `a` would equal 16 and `b` would equal 15, since you never call `b.increase()`.

Comment: Think of the `this.cVar++` as both a "get" and "set" operation. First you *get* the value from `this`, but since it doesn't exist directly on the object, you end up getting it from the `.prototype` object. So then you have the *set* operation, which sets it directly on `this`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, an object's prototype is shared between instances of the object, but the `this.cVar++` looks a little bit misleading.

I think its easier to explain if you rewrite

```
this.cVar++;
```

as

```
this.cVar = this.cVar + 1;
```

The important thing is that `this` refers to the object instance and not the prototype. So in `this.cVar + 1` it'll check the object instance to see if it has a `cVar` property. The first time `increase` is called, it doesn't. So JavaScript will look up the prototype chain until it finds it. So it finds `15`. However, when it does the actual assignment back to `this.cVar`, it sets the property on the object instance itself and not the prototype (a shadowing of sorts).

So in your example,

```
console.log(a.cVar); // returns property from `a` itself
console.log(b.cVar); // returns property from the prototype
```

We can show this by using [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
console.log( a.hasOwnProperty( "cVar" ) ); // true
console.log( b.hasOwnProperty( "cVar" ) ); // false
```

Comment: Was writing almost exactly the same answer, +1

Comment: Excellent description.

Answer (score 3):

Objects do, in fact, share the prototype with one another as your research has lead you to believe. However, as `go-oleg` eluded to, there is a concept of the prototype chain. The prototype chain has a couple of behaviors you have to understand.

When you try to access a property on an object, it recursively looks up the chain starting from the object and looks for the property, then returns the value (**This is what happens in the case of a read/get action**).

When you try to set the value on a property on an object, it doesn't bother to recurse up the chain to find the property in the chain. Instead, if it doesn't find one on the object, it just adds the property along with the value you set on the object itself. This effectively hides the property that is higher up the prototype chain (**This is what happens in the case of a write/set action**).

If you placed your value inside an object then tried to set the value however, it would recurse to the object reference in a read attempt and since you have a reference pointer to the object, you would be setting the value on the object directly which would have the outcome you were expecting:

```
function TestObj(){
}

TestObj.prototype = {
    cVar: 15,
    obj: { val: 5 },
    increase: function(){
        this.cVar++;
    },
    objInc: function() { 
        this.obj.val++;
    }
};

var a = new TestObj();
var b = new TestObj();
a.increase();
console.log(a.cVar);
console.log(b.cVar);

b.objInc();
console.log(a.obj.val);
console.log(b.obj.val);

//output
//16
//15
//6
//6
```

Hopefully that distinction clears up the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, "a" is an object, "b" is another, separate, object. 
You then call the increase function only on "a", not "b". Therefore, unless I'm off my rocker,
It would make sense that b.cVar = 15, since it was never incremented.

Comment: It's my belief that the OP thinks that calling `a.increase()` should also increase any other `TestObject` because of this line in his question: `... that functions' prototype is shared between all the objects for that particular type.`

Answer (score 0):

Your getting confused by the terminology, and `TestObject` `a` is the only `TestObject` that you call `increase()` on. So it makes sense that `a = 16` and `b = 16`, since you never call `b.increase()`.

> ... that functions' prototype is shared between all the objects for that particular type.

That doesn't mean that each time any `TestObject` calls `increase()` then every other `TestObject` and itself also increase their `cVar`. Your thinking of something similar to the way that an `EventListener` and `EventDispatcher` system is set up. That function's prototype shared between all the objects for that particular type means that each `TestObject` instance has the prototype you defined.